# RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() return null the second time called

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I have a probleme using the `RequestionContextHolder`. I have a keycloak token stored in the attributes of the context holder. I get the attributes at that line:

`RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();`

I need this keycloak token multiple times.

First, just after login, I get the requestAttributes and then the token (all is fine).

Then I need it later when using the application (after some clicks), the `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` returns null (not so good then).

Id don't understand why the first time all works well and then it just returns null.

I tried to put this in the web.xml but it does not change anything:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Are spawning  any new thread to execute your code where you are expecting RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every click in your application is a separate request, so they all have a separate RequestContext. Seems the token is put into request context only for this login request. Probably by the keycloak integration.

You will probably need something to recognize your user in the following requests. This would be a session, there are different types available. Then your client would need to senda sessionid or the token with every request.

For more details you would need to give us more context. How did you integrate keycloak? What do you want to do with the token?

Comment: I will store the token directly after the authentication and before any click.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Each HTTP request in a separate call. So may be you can preserve token once Login is success. Filters are available for that.

One way you can do is in by adding it in Session like this

Using Filter you can get HttpSession and add token into it like this.

```
HttpServletRequest req;

HttpSession session=req.getSession();

session.setAttribute("mytoken","token");
```

Later you can read it like this in each call

```
@GetMapping("logdetail")
public void getAllLogs(HttpSession session) {
    session.getAttribute("mytoken");
}
```